# Как поставить telegram-бота на хостинг?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытался поставить aiogram-бота на pythonanywhere, однако не получилось, т.к. вроде нужен ssl сертификат. (С telebot такого не требует)
Вопрос такой, если купить на том же firstvds сервер и там попробовать поставить бота, он будет работать? Или нужно ssl сертификат обязательно ещё докупать? На heroku aiogram ставится?

Comment: pythonanywhere дает свой ssl сертификат. Дополнительно ничего не нужно, если конечно вы не используете свой домен вместо предоставленного домена вида имя.pythonanywhere.com. С чего вы решили, что вам еще какой-то сертификат нужен?

Comment: Потому что я пытался там поставить бота, а он мне ошибку вернул мол нужен ssl

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/799299

Comment: Напишите конкретную ошибку, а не "мол нужен ssl"

Comment: Такой ошибки если купить вдс, не будет?

Comment: "Network is unreachable" - значит "сеть недоступна", а не "нужен ssl"'. Укажите конкретную ошибку, которая возникает именно у вас, а не в нагугленном вопросе на другом сайте, тогда уже можно будет смотреть.

Comment: Вот ошибка сама aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]

Comment: Эта ошибка и возникала:)

Comment: Ну тогда вам скорее всего подойдет ответ оттуда. Сертификат вообще тут ни при чем, не знаю откуда вы это взяли.

Answer (score 0):

`SSL` сертификат нужен если для взаимодействия с сервером телеграма будете использовать веб хуки. Либо настройте `letsencrypt` (это бесплатно) либо вместо веб хуков переключитесь на `long polling`